# Python Flask Pika Consumer (RabbitMQ)

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, pika

I have two little

> Python Flask

apps

1. Appone --> Producer
2. Apptwo --> Consumer

Both are in different `docker-container` and orchestrated by `docker-compose`

I dont get the Data from the Producer to the Consumer...Even when I start in apptwo the `start.consuming()` the Producer cant send any Data to the RabbitMQ Broker
Maybe someone can help me. Thank you very much

**docker-compose:**

```
version: '3'
services:

  appone:
    container_name: appone
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./appone
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: ./app.py        
    volumes:
      - './appone:/code/:cached'
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"

  apptwo:
    container_name: apptwo
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./apptwo
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
      FLASK_APP: ./app.py         
    volumes:
      - ./apptwo:/code:cached 
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"     

  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbit"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    labels:
      NAME: "rabbitmq"
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq/rabbitmq-isolated.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

**appone (Producer)**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import pika

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True

message = "Hello World, its me appone"


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host='rabbitmq'))
        channel = connection.channel()

        channel.queue_declare(queue='hello', durable=True)

        channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!', properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))

        connection.close()

        return {'message': message}


api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/api/appone/post')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Development
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)
```

**apptwo (Consumer)**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import pika
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True

data = []

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='rabbitmq'))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello', durable=True)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    data.append(body)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', on_message_callback=callback)

thread = Thread(channel.start_consuming())
thread.start()

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'message': data}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/api/apptwo/get')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5002)
```

**Goal**
In this easy example I just want to receice the data in apptwo and store it in the data list...

Thanks again!!

Comment: Did you provide the hostname, port, virtual host and user credentials while making the connection? Also, did you check if the message is getting published in the queue using the management plugin?

Comment: hi @bumblebee, the connection is up. I can use the container_name to "talk" to the rabbit mq container. The producer can send data to the broker. But the example for the consumer didnt get the data. Both consumer/producer are from the getting started tutorial for rabbitmq but are implemented in Flask.

Comment: Why do you want your consumer to be a flask app? Is there any specific need for that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In apptwo (Consumer):

```
thread = Thread(channel.start_consuming())
thread.start()
```

Here the constructor call of Thread is never called, since channel.start_consuming is called before, which is blocking. Changing your code to the following might help.

```
thread = Thread(target = channel.start_consuming)
thread.start()
```

Comment: i just need to say how simple this application of threading rabbitmq consumers is, thank you for your post!

there is no need for a cron job or scheduled task with this approach; it all runs within the Flask framework without any extra steps

Comment: hi @beep_check 
How do you capture the exception thrown by pika?
I am not able to capture it when using Threads.
Can you post the example code of your wsgi.py where you use RabbitMQ?